# Escaping the Dollar Symbol in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm using the `findAll` method in Groovy to find all instances of a particular string, however the problem is that the string I'm looking for contains the dollar symbol and I can't find a way to properly escape it.

```
file.findAll(/version=\"$version$\"/)
```

No matter how I try to escape it I always get an error along the lines of "variable version doesn't exist"